# FIPS Enable with openssl-3.0.8 on RHEL-7

Tags: linux, openssl, centos7, fips

On our CentOS 7 machine, we have installed openssl-3.0.8, and now we want to enable FIPS with it. Can you please give a step-by-step procedure from the installation of the FIPS version until enabling it on the machine?